# Trying to use 'reduce' instead of regular for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am trying to get the total 'stargazers_count' from a particular user's github repo. This code, using 'for' loop is working. But I would like to use 'reduce'. I am posting what I tried. Can someone point to me where I am wrong? 
The JSON can be viewed with this url,using your github username:

> https://api.github.com/users/${your username}/repos

This is the working code using for loop:

```
axios.get(response.data.repos_url)
  .then((res) => {

    let starCount = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<res.data.length; i++) // find out the total number of github stars
    {
        starCount += res.data[i].stargazers_count;
    }

      response.data.NoOfStars = starCount; // add the total stars as a property in response object
```

This is what I tried with 'reduce':

```
axios.get(response.data.repos_url)
  .then((res) => {

    let starCount = 0;
    const reducer = (acc, currVal) => acc + currVal.stargazers_count;

    arr = res.data;
    starCount = arr.reduce(reducer);
```

This did not work. If I can get a brief explanation of where and why I am wrong, it will be helpful.

Comment: What's the output and what do you expect it to be?

Comment: I expect it to be a number, value depends on the user, For eg. Dan Abramov, the stars count is 1427. The last time I tried.. I think I got a NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a starting value for your accumulator, otherwise reduce will assume that the first array element *is* the starting value and this would lead to a `NaN` result.

```
starCount = arr.reduce(reducer,0);
```